# path planning exceeding velocity limits of ur5

Tags: ros, universal-robot, ros-industrial, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using moveit for path planning of a ur5. After finding a valid path, I want to execute it to the real robot (which is connected and communicating properly) but I always receive an error message like:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1412925263.358047] Received a goal with velocities that are higher than 2.000000
```

the controller reports:

```
[INFO][ ... ]: Received new trajectory execution service request...
[WARNING][ ... ]: Controller handle reports status FAILED
[INFO][ ... ]: Execution completed: FAILED
```

any ideas how to fix that ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194667/path-planning-exceeding-velocity-limits-of-ur5/) by [psfa_fz](https://answers.ros.org/users/20415/psfa_fz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> [ERROR] [WallTime: 1412925263.358047] Received a goal with velocities that are higher than 2.000000

The error you are seeing is not caused by exceeding a real, actual velocity limit, but rather by a check in `ur_driver` that compares the requested velocities against a (private) parameter called `max_velocity`. The idea behind the check was most likely to be able to enforce a maximum velocity over a trajectory. This is currently not (very well) documented.

This parameter has a default of 2 rad/s (this is in joint space).

You can do two things:

1. add a `max_velocity` parameter to the `ur_driver` node **element** in `ur_bringup/launch/ur_common.launch`, like so:

   ```
   <node name="ur_driver" pkg="ur_driver" type="driver.py" args="...">
       <param name="max_velocity" type="double" value="YOUR_MAX_SPEED" />
   </node>
   ```
2. edit `ur_driver/src/ur_driver/driver.py`, and increase the default value for the `max_velocity` parameter.

For now, I'd recommend you use option 1 on a source checkout of the [universal_robot](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot) repository. Option 2 is really not a good idea.

I'll open a ticket on the github repository asking for this to be documented better.

---

Edit: for reference, see [universal_robot/issues/124](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/124).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1